# Math question about point transformations

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, differentiation

I am trying to prove the classic problem to showcase Lagrangian's scalar invariant property.

Namely, that if you have $x_i = \{ x_1, ...., x_n; t \}$ , you can then represent $L(x_1,....,\dot{x_1},...,t)$ and find the Euler-Lagrangian equations of motion:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x_i}}\right) -  \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_i} = 0.\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Now, if you introduce a new set of coordinates $q_j = \{ q_1, ...., q_n; t \}$, then you too can express the equations of motion via:

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_j}}\right) -  \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_j} = 0.\tag{2}
\end{equation}
I know I have to show that indeed this is the case, thus showing $L$ is scalar invariant under point transformations.

---

Now here's my problem.

I am going to use the simplest example I know: you only have $x$ and $q$ - only one degree of freedom.

I can define $x(q,t)$ and $q(x,t)$.

I can find the differential as follows:

\begin{equation}
dx = \frac{\partial x}{\partial q}dq + \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}dt\tag{3}
\end{equation}

And thus, I can find $\dot{x}$:

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dx}{dt}= \frac{\partial x}{\partial q} \frac{dq}{dt} + \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \tag{4}\\
\dot{x} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial q} \dot{q} + \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}.\tag{5}
\end{eqnarray}

I have read that you can turn that last equation into:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \dot{x}}{\partial \dot{q}}= \frac{\partial x}{\partial q} + \frac{\partial}{\partial q}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \tag{6}
\end{equation}

which would yield: 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \dot{x}}{\partial \dot{q}}= \frac{\partial x}{\partial q}.\tag{7}
\end{equation}

---

Here's my question:

I am not sure how to justify the change that yields this result. Because if I follow the equation closely, I would find this value:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\frac{dx}{dt}}{\frac{dq}{dt}} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial q} + \frac{d}{dq}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}.\tag{8}
\end{equation}

What am I missing or doing wrong that yields the intended result in partials rather than the result I just wrote above?

Comment: Read eqs. (6) and (8) where?

Comment: If you look at eq (6), I am not sure how you justify taking $\frac{\dot{x}}{\dot{q}}$ into it's partial from that is shown on eq(7).

Comment: Eq. (7) is correct.

Comment: Yes of course! I am not saying it's not. I want to understand how to get there. It does not seem clear to me in terms of how do you convert a $dq$ into a $\partial q$.

Comment: Eqs. (6) and (8) are not correct.

Comment: @Qmechanic, yes, this is why I am here. I am wondering if you could offer some insight.

Comment: If your main question is _How to derive eq. (7)?,_ then the short answer is _Use eq. (5)._

Comment: It is the main question @Qmechanic, but the issue if one looks closely is that $\dot{q}$ is not $\partial \dot{q}$.

I am wondering how can one justify that change, that is what I am seeing changing from one line to the other in eq(5) to eq(6).

Comment: There seems to be a dot missing (v4) in the last term of eq. (6).